# Create html from using form elements stored in database

Tags: java, html, json, spring, forms

I have a spring boot project, in which I’d like to create a dynamic html form.

My idea:

In the database, to have a ‘field elements’ table. Which will hold the details of what elements need to be displayed.

I’m just not sure how exactly to do this, as I’ve not used anything like jquery, angular or json forms before.

I would expect the database to hold something like this, but not sure on all the contents

| DisplayName | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Username | Text |
| Dropdown | List? |
| Password | Text |

Just needs to be a maven spring boot project. Which when i select a value from a dropdown list, it then goes to a new page which displays a HTML Form with the matching elements found in the database.

Currently i just hide the elements and then show them if the database value has been found. But this requires the elements having to be there on the html form. Meaning that if i add a value to the database, i also have to add it to the code. I want to be able to add extra fields to the database and then it automatically add to the front end

Comment: the easiest way that I can think of would be to put html code (which would be added dynamically to your page) in your database and then return it as a string to the front end. Some javascript code can then be used to attach that string to, say, a  div element (or a form element), which serves as a container for your dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thanks, yeah did something similar to that and it works. Not exactly what I wanted but does the job